# pgfplots: minor xticklabels?

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to explicitly set the labels on the minor x-ticks, but this

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xtick={-1.5,-1,-0.5, 0.0,0.5, 1.0,1.5},
xticklabels={$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$,$e$, $f$},
minor xtick={-0.7},
minor xticklabels={$z$}
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=*]
coordinates {%
  (-1, 1)
  (-0.75, 0.5625)
  (-0.5, 0.25)
  (-0.25, 0.0625)
  (0, 0)
  (0.25, 0.0625)
  (0.5, 0.25)
  (0.75, 0.5625)
  (1, 1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

fails with

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/minor xtick labels', to w
hich you passed '$z$', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Any hints?

Comment: I don't think minor ticks have labels. Would using an `extra x tick` be an option?

Comment: Yep, that'd do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pgfplots` doesn't label minor ticks I think, but for a case like your example it has the concept of `extra x ticks`:

```
extra x ticks={-0.7},
extra x tick labels={$z$}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xtick={-1.5,-1,-0.5, 0.0,0.5, 1.0,1.5},
xticklabels={$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$,$e$, $f$},
extra x ticks={-0.7},
extra x tick labels={$z$}
]
\addplot[smooth,blue,mark=*]
coordinates {%
  (-1, 1)
  (-0.75, 0.5625)
  (-0.5, 0.25)
  (-0.25, 0.0625)
  (0, 0)
  (0.25, 0.0625)
  (0.5, 0.25)
  (0.75, 0.5625)
  (1, 1)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```